# How to generate md5-hashes for Pipe delimited file IN SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, md5, generate

Hey i am able to generate the MD5 hash for text in SQL Server Using `HASHBYTES` 
The syntax is

```
SET @MD5HASH =  CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'Filename'), 2)
```

I want to generate MD5-hash For a text file (Content).

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: should be moved to https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Want to generate MD5# for a 1GB of a text file